# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: in GRT

Tags: c++, xcode

I am new to Xcode (version 8) and I downloaded the Gesture Recognition Toolkit it is a C++ machine learning algorithm "https://github.com/nickgillian/grt".
The problem is when I build the given examples I get the following errors:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"GRT::MovingAverageFilter::MovingAverageFilter(unsigned int, unsigned int)",referenced from:
  _main in AdaBoostExample.o
 "GRT::MovingAverageFilter::~MovingAverageFilter()", referenced from:
   _main in AdaBoostExample.o
```

Comment: Are you only including the libraries header file, but not linking with the actual library?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  
As far as I understand I added the library folder in the Xcode project , so I believe that it is linked

Comment: @H.A: The error message says otherwise. And adding a folder just tells XCode _where_ to look for libraries, not _which_ libraries it needs.

Comment: @MSalters actually I did include the library

Comment: #include <GRT/GRT.h>
using namespace GRT;
using namespace std;
@MSalters

Comment: @H.A: That's the _header_ and the _namespace_. Not the _library_.